Manual input is not operated in NZ-Range-Picker
| angular   | 13.2.7   |
| ng-zorro-antd   | 13.1.1  |
 <nz-range-picker [(ngModel)]="dateRange" (ngModelChange)="dateRangeChange($event)" nzAllowClear="false"></nz-range-picker>

dateRange = [new Date(), new Date()]

If you enter the manual with the keyboard in the NZ-Range-Picker, the date will not change.
The html has [nzShowTime]="'true'" value, so if you can adjust the time, the Manual input is applied.
Is there any way to do it without a time?
